# How to retrieve timestamp value "-infinity" from PostgreSQL using JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to fetch values stored in PostgreSQL 9.1. The field type is "timestamp with time zone". The value stored is "-infinity". When I use JPA / Hibernate annotation it provides me with a weird date value. My Entity Java class has declared the date as java.util.Date().

Here is the System.out when I print my Date from Java that JPA / Hibernate retrieves from PGSQL.

```
292269055-12-02 23:00:00.0
```

Here is a snippet of my Java Entity showing annotation for my date type.

```
    @Column( name = "from_date")
    private Date    from_date;
```

I've read somewhere that PostgreSQL's JDBC driver can store and read timestamp values stored as "-infinity" and "infinity". If Hibernate / JPA doesn't support that is it possible to use custom converter to get these values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need specifically the Postgre Infinity? Otherwise just create your own. The Java Date maximum year and the Postgre Infinity Year are different anyway.

```
public class InfinityProducer {

  public Date getInfinity() {
     Date date = new Date();
     date.setYear(292278994);
     return date;
  }
}
```